# Identifying Disconnected Exchange Mailboxes in Powershell CSV export

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

I've got a PS script (see below) that will give me a list of all mailboxes with item count, DB name, and size.  However, I noticed that disconnected mailboxes are included in this list.  That's totally fine, but I was looking for a way to flag the disconnected mailboxes in the CSV export.  Does anyone have any thoughts?  I've looked around quite a bit, but haven't found anything.  Thanks!

```
Get-MailboxDatabase "DB9" | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount, DatabaseName | Export-CSV d:\mailboxscript\mailboxesizesDB1.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the DisconnectDate is not equal to null:

Get-MailboxDatabase "DB9" | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount, DatabaseName,@{n='Disconnected';e={$_.DisconnectDate -ne $null}}| Export-CSV d:\mailboxscript\mailboxesizesDB1.csv